# D3 Zoom in version 3

Tags: d3.js, zooming

There are a few examples on Stack Overflow on how to achieve a pan and zoom in a force graph using D3, but they all use D3 Version 2, not the latest Version 3.

For example, here is one solution: http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/QMKm3/

But, it appears that in Version 3, applying `transform="translate(0,0) scale(0.5)"` on the core `svg` view does not seem to work.

Please excuse my coffeescript if you are not familiar with reading it:

```
height = null
width = null
svg = null

resizeHandler = ->
  height = $("#fcMiddle").height()
  width = $("#fcMiddle").width()
  console.log height+"x"+width
  rerender()

$(window).resize resizeHandler

redraw = ->
  #console.log "here", d3.event.translate, d3.event.scale
  svg.attr "transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")" + " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")"

svg = d3.select("#fcMiddle").append("svg").attr("width", width).attr("height", height).attr("pointer-events", "all")

rerender = ->
  $("#fcMiddle svg").empty()
  svg.append('svg:g').call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", redraw)).append('svg:g').append('svg:rect').attr('width', width).attr('height', height).attr('fill', 'white')
  color = d3.scale.category20()
  force = d3.layout.force().charge(-120).linkDistance(30).size([width, height])
  d3.json "/data/systems.json", (error, graph) ->
    console.log graph
    force.nodes(graph.nodes).links(graph.links).start()
    link = svg.selectAll(".link").data(graph.links).enter().append("line").attr("class", "link").style("stroke-width", (d) ->
      Math.sqrt d.value
    )
    node = svg.selectAll(".node").data(graph.nodes).enter().append("circle").attr("class", "node").attr("r", 5).style("fill", (d) ->
      color d.group
    ).call(force.drag)
    node.append("title").text (d) ->
      d.name

    force.on "tick", ->
      link.attr("x1", (d) ->
        d.source.x
      ).attr("y1", (d) ->
        d.source.y
      ).attr("x2", (d) ->
        d.target.x
      ).attr "y2", (d) ->
        d.target.y

      node.attr("cx", (d) ->
        d.x
      ).attr "cy", (d) ->
        d.y
```

This is nearly identical to the version in JavaScript [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045). I redraw everything if the window gets rescaled, and I reuse the  by clearing its contents every time I re-draw everything. These things should not affect the transformation for zoom.

Comment: D3 and SVG are independent, so for applying an attribute such as `transform` to an SVG it doesn't matter which version you use. As far as I can see, the code you posted should work -- what do you mean when you say that it doesn't work?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I see the transformation property being applied to the root `<svg>`, but there is absolutely no visual difference in the force directed graph.

Comment: Could you post a complete example that demonstrates the problem please?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Go to http://54.200.163.87:3000/, type a username and password and hit "Register" (no confirmation needed), hit "Create a Fleet", enter "Test" or whatever into the title, hit "Create Fleet", and you will see the graph in the middle of the interface. The code is in coffeescript and easily read in the browser (map.coffee). I apologize for giving you a link but I can't really post all the code here very easily.

Comment: Ok, in the source for that page I'm getting links to about 50 Javascript files. Could you provide a smaller example? In any case, [here](http://bl.ocks.org/benzguo/4370043) is an example that has force layout with zoom behaviour in D3v3.

Comment: If you simply do what I said before and use chrome or some other developer tool in the "inspect element" - right click on the page - you will see the HTML source, and under the source tab, you should see map.coffee

Comment: I also give the source here... And the link you gave was d3v2

Comment: Ok, my bad -- here's an example that definitely uses v3 -- https://vida.io/documents/HQNtWrJWyYPScwwJM

Comment: And it looks like you're setting `transform` on the SVG itself -- try setting it on a `g` element that contains everything like in the example I've posted.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Silly question but, in my current code, how to I make it all be under a "g"? I can't find where you actually create the ".node" obejcts

Comment: The `svg` variable I'm translating is a `g` element -- `var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").call(zoom).append("g")`.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I know that but in the code in my question, how do I make the force graph add the nodes BELOW the g?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Never mind, everything is working perfectly now. Can you post your answer of translating a "g" holding the nodes? That was the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're applying the `transform` to an element, make sure that it's not the `svg` element -- `transform`ing that will have no effect (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform) for more information). You can however add a `g` element at the top level (i.e. everything else is added below that) and `transform` that.